# Asymptotic decay rate of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a stochastic process $\{X_t > 0: t\ge 0\}$ and $\{a_t>0:t\ge 0\}$. Assume $a_t$ grows unbounded almost surely. Namely:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}{\sf P}(a_t < ct) = 0
$$
I am interested in the ratio
$$
R_t = \frac{{\sf E}(e^{-a_t}X_t)}{{\sf E}(X_t)} \stackrel{?}{\to} 0
$$
This is upper-bounded by 1, so it will not blow up at least.

I want to know what should be an extra assumption for $X_t$ to conclude the ratio decays to zero.

Some attempts:

- If $a_t \ge ct$ almost surely, then $R_t \le e^{-ct} \to 0$.
- If $X_t$ and $a_t$ independent, then $R_t = {\sf E}(e^{-a_t})\to 0$.
- Using Jensen's inequality to claim $\frac{1}{{\sf E}(X_t)}\le {\sf E}\big(\frac{1}{X_t}\big)$. Then reversed Cauchy-Schwarz type inequality may apply, but this requires $X_t$ to be bounded from below and above.

These are quite restrictive.

- I was thinking Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applies to the numerator and then
  $$
  R_t \le \frac{1}{{\sf E}(X_t)} \sqrt{{\sf E}(X_t^2){\sf E}(e^{-2a_t})} = \sqrt{\frac{{\sf E}(X_t^2)}{{\sf E}(X_t)}} \cdot \sqrt{{\sf E}(e^{-2a_t})}
  $$
  I stuck here because $\sqrt{\frac{{\sf E}(X_t^2)}{{\sf E}(X_t)}} \ge 1$ but I do not have a nice upper bound.

Anyone has a niche idea on less restrictive condition on $X_t$ so that $e^{-a_t}$ dominates the dynamics and $R_t$ decays?

---

**Edit**:

I think I have incorrectly written $a_t$ grows unbounded a.s.
It should be
$$
{\sf P}\Big(\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{a_t}{t} > c\Big) = 1
$$

Rewrite
$$
R_t = {\sf E}\Big(e^{-a_t}\frac{X_t}{{\sf E}(X_t)}\Big)
$$
Then the claim becomes
$$
e^{-a_t}Y_t \to 0\quad \text{in }L^1
$$
where $Y_t= \frac{X_t}{{\sf E}(X_t)}$. Since ${\sf E}(Y_t) = 1$ for all $t$,  can we say $Y_t$ converges to 1 in $L^1$?
I think then if $X_t$ is integrable for all $t$ then we $L^1$ convergence of $e^{-a_t}Y_t$.

Comment: For some $c$?  For all $c$?

Comment: @Michael For some constant $c$ here. Maybe we can interchange $ct$ by (any) $M$ to make it weaker. I think either case should work under some mild condition on $X_t$, as we are normalizing with $E(X_t)$.

Answer (score 1):

So, your question seems to be the following (and leave a comment if I missed anything in my rephrasing): if I have a random process $Z_t$ (which you can view as $e^{-a_t}$) that is bounded between $0$ and $1$ a.s. and goes to $0$ a.s., and a process $Y_t$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = 1$, and $Y_t > 0$ a.s., does $Z_t Y_t$ go to $0$ in $L^1$?

This should be false. In particular, consider $\Omega = [0, 1]$ with uniform measure, $Z_t$ be the indicator of the set $[0, \min(1/t, 1)]$, and $Y_t = \max(1, t) Z_t$. Then, $Y_t Z_t = Y_t$, and it converges to $1$ in $L^1$ even though it almost surely goes to 0.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the problem! it becomes lot more clear with your reformulation. In this case, $Z_t$ goes to 0 with probability 1. So the condition on $Z_t$ should be stronger than just saying converges to zero almost surely.

Comment: By Hölder's inequality, we have $\mathbb{E}(Y_tZ_t) \le \|Z_t\|_\infty$, and therefore the condition is to find $\|Z_t\|_\infty \to 0$. Your counterexample is clearly the case where $\|Z_t\|_\infty = 1$ for all $t$. However, the original problem has a specific form $Z_t = e^{-a_t}$. Does this help?

Comment: Not much; the only exception you might raise would be that $Z_t = 0$ a.s. means $a_t = \infty$ a.s. which is not a number per se (as per the answer, we are viewing $a_t = -\log Z_t$. However, you can just put a very small value on those sets instead (like $2^{-t}$), and fudge things accordingly. The example is still -essentially- correct I think.